# Derivative of "retarded" solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions

This is in Peter Woit's book towards the end of chapter 12. We were studying green function method and applying to Schrodinger equation.

The prototypical setting is we want to solve for $\psi$ in
$$ D\psi=J$$ for $D$ the differential operator and $J$ is the source.
We defined $\psi_+(q,t)=\theta(t)\psi(q,t)$ we then take

$$D \psi_{+}(q, t)=(D \theta(t)) \psi(q, t)+\theta(t) D \psi(q, t)=i\delta(t)\psi(q, t)+\theta(t)J$$

Now the book claims that
$$ (D \theta(t)) \psi(q, t)+\theta(t) D \psi(q, t)=i\delta(t)\psi(q, t)=i\delta(t)\psi(q, 0)$$ which confuses me, as why would the second term vanish?

Comment: Presumably Woit assumes that $D\psi=0$.